# inserting tenant error sitecore 9.2 SXA 1.9

Tags: sxa, powershell-extensions

When I try inserting a tenant this error appears I tried reinstalling SXA but no difference happens
[image]

```
CodeBeside class "Cognifide.PowerShell.SitecoreIntegrations.Applications.PowerShellRunner,Cognifide.PowerShell" not found. (method: Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.CodeBeside.OnInit(EventArgs e)).
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: `System.Exception: CodeBeside class "Cognifide.PowerShell.SitecoreIntegrations.Applications.PowerShellRunner,Cognifide.PowerShell" not found. (method: Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.CodeBeside.OnInit(EventArgs e)).`

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[Exception: CodeBeside class "Cognifide.PowerShell.SitecoreIntegrations.Applications.PowerShellRunner,Cognifide.PowerShell" not found. (method: Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.CodeBeside.OnInit(EventArgs e)).]
   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Error.Raise(String error, String method) +133
   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.CodeBeside.CreateCodeBeside(String type) +113
   Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.CodeBeside.OnInit(EventArgs e) +232
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +454
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +219
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +219
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +219
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +219
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +219
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +219
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +219
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +219
   System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index) +239
   Sitecore.Shell.DefaultPage.OnInit(EventArgs e) +157
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +454
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1719
```

Comment: I think you need a newer version of SPE for this. The Cognifide namespace was removed quite some time ago.

Comment: It's not clear what version of SPE you have installed but you might as well install the latest 6.x version.

Comment: I was using version 5.0 but now installed version 6.1.1 and still the same error @MichaelWest

Comment: Delete all the Cognifide dlls and configs.

Comment: @MichaelWest ya after deleting all powershell related files and reinstalling it worked thanks alot